# Javascript reference object with passed data?

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, parameter-passing

I'm trying to make a function in which I can reference an object using information passed into that function. Here's some example code:

```
        function pass(n) {
            alert(object.n);
        }
        pass("type");
```

In this example I want to be able to alert with the contents of object at type location. How can I do this such that it will work? It also doesn't work when I instead pass a variable like so:

```
            function pass(n) {
                alert(object.n);
            }
            var m = "type";
            pass(m);
```

This is all assuming that my object has something in object.n or object.type.

Any info would help, thanks!

Comment: bracket notation..... Looking for the duplicate

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, that one was on my quicklist :-)

Comment: @Bergi That is on my other computer. ;) Maybe I should make it a Google Doc. lol... Or I should make a browser plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, wasn't sure how to word my question to find a duplicate.